# SQL Server getting stuck / lock on simple truncate when used by C# application

Tags: c#, sql-server, truncate

I have a problem using the `TRUNCATE` command inside my C# application to delete all the data in a Table.

The table has about 1M rows.

If I execute the query right into the Database using SQL Management Studio, it takes 1s to truncate, if I execute my c# app, the SQL process goes crazy (memory usage and cpu going wild) and it stays lock forever.

Below the relevant code.

Connection string

```
<add name="KnowledgeBaseDB" connectionString="Data Source=LIS-500LGH2;Initial Catalog=KnowledgeBaseDB;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Code

```
            private static string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["KnowledgeBaseDB"].ToString();
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE [dbo].[FileTmp]"))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    com.Connection = conn;
                    com.CommandTimeout = 0;
                    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
```

I am not using `SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION ON`.

The only one acessing the Table is my application and I do the following by this order:

1. Insert data into `FileTmp` using `sqlBulkCopy`.
2. Merge different data into `FileTmp`.
3. Loop select 1000 rows from `FileTmp` and copy them to "File" table.
4. Truncate `FileTmp`

I know that the bulk copy is still executing on SQL Server even after my App finishes the `using(SqlConnection...)`

Comment: Can you provide the connection string as well?

Comment: Ofc, here: "Data Source=LIS-500LGH2;Initial Catalog=KnowledgeBaseDB;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient". I also Edited and added to the question to be more perceptive over there.

Comment: Deleting 1M rows isn't simple. Are any other operations using that table? Does the database use snapshot isolation?

Comment: `TRUNCATE TABLE` is a metadata-only operation.  It will complete instantly, unless blocked by another session.

Comment: your best bet is to run a profiler trace to see what is happening when issuing the truncate via your app

Comment: It's definitely [*not* metadata-only](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/truncate-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), it's transactional and the reason its' faster is that it doesn't record individual records in the log. The data *is* logged though and *can* be recovered with a rollback

Comment: SQL Server has transnational DDL.  TRUNCATE TABLE just updates the data allocation metadata.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft and logs that, allowing rollbacks. That's explained in the documentation links and a lot of articles that explain the operation *is* logged, like [The Myth that DROP and TRUNCATE TABLE are Non-Logged](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/05/sql-performance/drop-truncate-log-myth). In a database with snapshot isolation I expect that concurrent reads will result in a lot of row copies in TempDB, resulting in a lot of CPU/RAM usage

Comment: Metadata operations are logged, making them transnational.  The individual row are not deleted, and not logged.  Only the system metadata is updated and logged.

Comment: @gn66 are you using SNAPSHOT isolation? Implicit transactions through TransactionScope perhaps? Who reads/writes to `FileTemp`?

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos I am not using "SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION ON". The only one acessing the Table is my application and I do the following by this order: 1. Insert data into FileTmp using sqlBulkCopy. 2. Merge different data into FileTmp. 3. Loop select 1000 rows from "FileTmp" and copy them to "File" table. 4. Truncate FileTmp

Comment: Have you at any point run something like sp_WhoIsActive or queried the DMVs to see if there is blocking going on while you are trying to truncate this table? Is it possible that step 3 is holding a transaction open?

Comment: @JM_ I have, I actually think its also step 3, just discovered the bulk copy is still executing on SQL Server even after my App finishes the "using(SqlConnection...)"